# MySQL Group By custom timestamp

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to get results from the database which is grouped by date. The resulting touples should be grouped by date which ranges from 5 am to 5 am. In other words the cutoff should be on 5 am and not midnight 12 am. I can do `GROUP BY DAY(timestamp)` to group by normal day but what if I have to vary the time and each records should be grouped from 5 am to 5 am ? How should I change the query ? Thanks ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply subtract 5 hours from each datetime value you have, and then convert it to a date. Then you can group by the result.

```
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(timestamp, INTERVAL 5 HOUR))
```